# fatal error in phpmyadmin when relating tables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, phpmyadmin, backend

I just created my database on localhost using phpmyadmin, I want to relate the tables and when I enter the designer option I get a "fatal error" and I do not understand what happens.

This is the first time that I have created a database in phpmyadmin, I have tried creating another database and I get the same error.

I attach the error:

```js
{
    "pma_version": "4.8.3",
    "browser_name": "IE",
    "browser_version": 11,
    "user_os": "Win",
    "server_software": "Apache/2.4.35 (Win64) PHP/7.2.10",
    "user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
    "locale": "es",
    "configuration_storage": "disabled",
    "php_version": "7.2.10",
    "exception_type": "js",
    "exception": {
        "mode": "stack",
        "name": "TypeError",
        "message": "Unable to get the 'style' property of null or undefined reference",
        "stack": [
            {
                "line": "292",
                "func": "",
                "column": "",
                "uri": "index.php?v=4.8.3",
                "scriptname": "index.php"
            },
            {
                "func": "Main",
                "line": "265",
                "column": "5",
                "uri": "index.php?v=4.8.3",
                "scriptname": "index.php"
            },
            {
                "func": "Anonymous function",
                "line": "38",
                "column": "5",
                "uri": "index.php?v=4.8.3",
                "scriptname": "index.php"
            },
            {
                "func": "new_func",
                "line": "248",
                "column": "21",
                "uri": "index.php?v=4.8.3",
                "scriptname": "index.php"
            },
            {
                "func": "w.event.dispatch",
                "line": "2",
                "column": "41706",
                "uri": "index.php?v=4.8.3",
                "scriptname": "index.php"
            },
            {
                "func": "$event.dispatch",
                "line": "374",
                "column": "2",
                "uri": "index.php?v=4.8.3",
                "scriptname": "index.php"
            },
            {
                "func": "y.handle",
                "line": "2",
                "column": "39718",
                "uri": "index.php?v=4.8.3",
                "scriptname": "index.php"
            },
            {
                "func": "trigger",
                "line": "2",
                "column": "69549",
                "uri": "index.php?v=4.8.3",
                "scriptname": "index.php"
            },
            {
                "func": "Anonymous function",
                "line": "2",
                "column": "70138",
                "uri": "index.php?v=4.8.3",
                "scriptname": "index.php"
            },
            {
                "func": "each",
                "line": "2",
                "column": "2563",
                "uri": "index.php?v=4.8.3",
                "scriptname": "index.php"
            },
            {
                "func": "w.prototype.each",
                "line": "2",
                "column": "1231",
                "uri": "index.php?v=4.8.3",
                "scriptname": "index.php"
            }
        ],
        "incomplete": "false",
        "partial": "true",
        "uri": "index.php?"
    },
    "script_name": "index.php",
    "microhistory": null
}
```

Comment: This is a JS error … so I would maybe try it in a proper browser first. (Referring to `"browser_name": "IE"` here ;-)) Apart from that, fixing issues in 3rd-party software is not really the purpose of this site; you should rather file a bug report with the makers of phpMyAdmin …

Answer (score 0):

After several hours looking for the error I found the bug, I had not configured the design view of phpmyadmin, this post helped me [How do I enable phpMyAdmin's Designer view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166687/how-do-i-enable-phpmyadmins-designer-view)